How to find download url from a given website to be used in wget?
I try to obtain a publicly available historical document from an archive in Germany, however, the download never starts as I believe the PDF file is too big to be downloaded within a certain time, so any browser will stop the download.
The website is https://recherche-stadtarchiv.leipzig.de/actaproweb/search.xhtml
insert
Nr. 3198 - Hauptbuch über die Beiträge zum Stadtschuldentilgungsfonds - 1819-1842
and click on the title "StadtAL_0008_Nr_3198" and the actual supposed to start.
However I do not find the actual download link within the html code using code inspection.
Where is the actual link to the file on the server to be used with wget? I would need to obtain the link to the pdf file in order to download it properly as the download within a browser (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) aborts each time.
Edit
As far as I am concerned, I do not have to log in to the site to download files. I have done it myself several times. However, it seems that the document in question is so large (10 GB+?) that the download in the browser stops every time I try. I have already been able to download smaller documents (5 GB per PDF file) on the site without logging in and without any problems, even from the same type of documents like
Nr. 3171 - Kataster über den Wert sämtlicher Häuser und Grundstücke - 1807-1808

I'm seeing an <a href=...> right there in the HTML, though? Were you using "View source" or were you using Developer Tools? The former will not show you any dynamically added tags – you need to use DevTools most of the time.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See Edit above.

wget --output-file="$wget_log" --content-on-error --no-cache --trust-server-names --spider 'https://recherche-stadtarchiv.leipzig.de/actaproweb/image.xhtml?id=b1bc83cd-d926-4f89-8725-59bbf2d464da' It's giving me https://recherche-stadtarchiv.leipzig.de/actaproweb/login.xhtml.  It wants credentials.

Hi JayCravens, the Webmaster just mailed to me stating that now it should work without a prompt asking for credentials. How do I obtain the full download link to be used in wget?

Can anyone help me with this one?

I think the web server can't find this file: "StadtAL_0008_Nr_3198.pdf" because to download "StadtAL_0008_Nr_3171.pdf" with wget there is no problem.
